# How to properly use multiple destructors in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In my game I am creating some big class, which store references to smaller classes, which store some references too. And during gameplay I need to recreate this big class with all its dependencies by destroying it and making new one.

It's creation looks like that:

```
ABigClass::ABigClass()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("BigClass created"));
    SmallClass1 = NewObject<ASmallClass>();
    SmallClass2 = NewObject<ASmallClass>();
    ......
}
```

And it works. Now I want to destroy and re create it by calling from some function

```
BigClass->~ABigClass();
BigClass= NewObject<ABigClass>();
```

which destroys BigClass and creates new one with new small classes, the problem is, that old small classes are still in memory, I can see it by logging their destructors.

So I try to make such destructor for Big Class

```
ABigClass::~ABigClass()
{
    SmallClass1->~ASmallClass();
    SmallClass2->~ASmallClass();
    ......
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("BigClass destroyed"));
}
```

SmallClass is inherited from other class, which have its own constructor and destructor, but I do not call it anywhere.

Sometimes it works, but mostly causes UE editor to crash when code compiled, or when game starsted/stopped.

Probably there is some more common way to do what I want to do? Or some validation which will prevent it from crash?

Please help.

Comment: Awooga! Awooga! Awooga! Danger Will Robinson! Manual calls to the destructor detected! Danger! Danger! (seriously, don't do that)

Comment: You should not be destroying objects explicitly at all.

Comment: Short of placement-new semantics (which you're not doing, and probably shouldn't be even if you were), you really have no reason to be executing destructors manually. That in itself is a rather pungent code smell.

Comment: Unreal has its own memory model for code like this. If you want to destroy an object created by `NewObject` you null all of its strong references (UPROPERTY)s and wait for the garbage collector to pick it up. If you've null'd all the references and your object is still not gone then you've either got a horrible bug or more references.

Comment: To add to the above, you can weakly reference an object using `TWeakObjectPtr`. (There's also `TWeakPtr` which is used for unreal's implementation of more traditional style smart pointers, and won't work with `NewObject`).

Comment: Instead of recreating a new big class in place, you should probably destroy the old big class with its dependencies and create a new big class with its new dependencies. **Explicit call to destructor in user code is suspicious**. If you don't know what you do using such low-level construct, then you can have memory leaks, exception unsafe code and other subtil problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do this.
First, I needed to get rid of all UPROPERTYs, related to classes, which I am going to destroy, except UPROPERTYs in a class, which controls their creation and destruction. If I need to expose these classes to blueprints somewhere else, it can be done with BlueprintCallable getter and setter functions.

Then I needed to calm down UE's garbage collector, which destroy objects on hot reload and on game shutdown in random order, ignoring my destructor hierarchy, which results in attempt to destroy already destroyed object and crash. So before doing something in destructor with other objects, I need to check if there is something to destroy, adding IsValidLowLevel() check.

And instead of delete keyword it is better to use DestructItem() function, it seems to be more garbage collector-friendly in many ways.

Also, I did not found a way to safely destroy objects, which are spawned in level. Probably because they are referenced somewhere else, but I dont know where, but since they are lowest level in my hierarchy, i can just Destroy() them in the world, and do not bother when exactly they will disappear from memory by garbage collector's will.

Anyway, I ended up with following code:

```
void AGameModeBase::ResetGame()
{
    if (BigClass->IsValidLowLevel()) {
        DestructItem(BigClass);
        BigClass= nullptr;
        BigClass= NewObject<ABigClass>();   
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Bigclass recreated"));
    }
}

ABigClass::~ABigClass()
{
    if (SmallClass1) {
        if (SmallClass->IsValidLowLevel())
        {
            DestructItem(SmallClass1);  
        }
        SmallClass1 = nullptr;
    }   
    if (SmallClass2) {
        if (SmallClass->IsValidLowLevel())
        {
            DestructItem(SmallClass2);  
        }
        SmallClass2 = nullptr;
    }   
    ...
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("BigClass destroyed"));
}

ASmallClass::~ASmallClass()
{
    for (ATinyClass* q : TinyClasses)
    {
        if (q->IsValidLowLevel())
        {
            q->Destroy();
        }
    }
    TinyClasses = {};

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("SmallClass destroyed"));
}
```

And no crashes. Probably someone will find it useful in cases it is needed to clear game lever from hierarchy of objects without fully reloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually call a destructor. Replace

```
SmallClass1->~ASmallClass();
SmallClass2->~ASmallClass();
```

with either

```
delete SmallClass1;
SmallClass1 = nullptr;
```

or by nothing if those type are ref-counted by unreal in some fashion (likely).

Comment: Things created by `NewObject` are indeed reference counted. If they are not referenced by any pointer marked with `UPROPERTY`, then they are garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks George for info about UPROPERTY. Seems like I must set UPROPERTY only in class which is responsible for creation of these objects to avoid this object to be stored forever somewhere else.

Though, nullification of these references do not solve the problem, because I need the whole hierarchy of objects to go away at once, without waiting garbage collector to decide when it is time.